# how to tell $_GET parameters are equal to or not equal to

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a dynamic page with $_GET vars(params) and I have it working if the var is equal to something, it will display content. But if the var doesn't equal something, then it either displays the content still, or doesn't display the error; or displays the error and the content at the same time

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['type'])){
    header("location: ?type=login");
} else {
    $type = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['type']))));
}
if($type != 'login' || $type != 'register'){
    ?>
    <h1>What your looking for can't be found!</h1>
    <?php
}
if($type == 'login'){
    ?>
    <h1>Login page:</h1>
    <?php
}
if($type == 'register'){
    ?>
    <h1>Register page:</h1>
    <?php
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code:

1. Your check for the error needs to use `&&` and not `||`. You want to see if `login` *AND* `register` are both not used.
2. You need to use `if/else if` statements to make sure only one condition is ever present.

Check this code out:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['type'])){
    header("location: ?type=login");
} else {
    $type = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['type']))));
}

if($type != 'login' && $type != 'register'){
    ?>
    <h1>What your looking for can't be found!</h1>
    <?php
} else if($type == 'login'){
    ?>
    <h1>Login page:</h1>
    <?php
} else if($type == 'register'){
    ?>
    <h1>Register page:</h1>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because you are using a **comparative** operator in your check:

`if($type != 'login' || $type != 'register')`

Essentially, this is two separate conditions; the first will will evaluate to `true` when the page is not `login`, the second will evaluate to `true` when the page is not `register`. **However**, they're not checking for **each other**.

The first condition will consider `register` to be valid, as `register` is valid for `if($type != 'login')`. The second will consider `login` to be valid, as `login` is valid for `if($type != 'register')`.

You need to ensure that **neither** of these pages are allowed, by using the **AND** comparator (`&&`): `if($type != 'login' && $type != 'register')`

However, for the matter, you don't need to worry about setting the `$type` variable at all. Simply check what `_GET['type']` equates to at the same time that you're checking it's set:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'login') {
    ?>
    <h1>Login page:</h1>
    <?php
}
else if (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'register') {
    ?>
    <h1>Register page:</h1>
    <?php
}
else {
    header("location: ?type=login");
}
```

Also, please note that the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is outright [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**parameterised queries**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to work out the logic a little more...if, else if, else. Case handling is the problem.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['type'])){
    header("location: ?type=login");
} else if(isset($_GET['type'] {
    If ($_GET['type'] !== "") {
    $type = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['type']))));
    }
}
......
?>
```

Sorry for the half baked answer, I'm on my phone and it's not very code-friendly